# Saving data with eloquent in a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am trying to achieve a simple insert into a pivot table but I cannot understand the principle why it does not work.

I have a Languages table which contains an id, name and code populated with languages. And I have a users table populated with users. The middle table is users_languages which has the columns user_id and and language_id.

My request has something like this

```
{
   "languages": [1, 2] -> language ids
}
```

My languages method into the Users model looks like this:

```
public function language() : BelongsToMany
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Language::class, 'users_languages')
        ->withPivot('user_id', 'language_id');
}
```

I am trying to add the languages like this:

```
public function setLanguages(array $languages) : self
{
    $this->language()->delete();
    $this->language()->createMany($languages);

    return $this;
}
```

The result I get is actually the its trying to create a new entry into the Languages table instead of just making a connection between the user_id and language_id.

I was looking through the documentation and some articles how this works but I none of the solutions I found worked. I am using Lumen 5.5 for my project. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

```
public function setLanguages(array $languages) : self
{
    $this->language()->attach($languages);

    return $this;
}
```

Use `sync()` if you want to remove the existing pivot entries.

```
public function setLanguages(array $languages) : self
{
    $this->language()->sync($languages);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I actually tried both methods before and I was getting errors that the methods do not exists and now suddenly works. The only issue I have now is that looks like the language_id now finally is passed but somehow my user_id is now null. Do you think I have to add it different somehow into the language method?

Comment: Can you log the query with `\DB::enableQueryLog(); [...] dd($log = \DB::getQueryLog());`?

Comment: What's the result of `dd($languages);`?

Comment: The languages contians only the language ids, do I have to add manually the user_id? Seems a bit not correct to do that.

Comment: Can you post the query log?

Comment: I cannot get any output, I get only the error: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users_languages` (`language_id`, `user_id`) values (150, ))",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/175997/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-ninetyhh).